# How to combine these two select statements

Tags: mysql

I would like to combine these 2 statements but can't seem to get it right.

I need 3 total columns. One for total, month and losses.

Here is what I have so far

```
SELECT Count(patient1.patient_id) AS total FROM patient AS total;
SELECT Count(patient2.patient_id) AS losses, patient2.mo AS `month`
FROM patient AS patient2
WHERE patient1.rx_exp BETWEEN '2010-10-01' AND '2010-11-01';
```

**EDIT** I need to have all three columns on a single row.

Comment: Your first query doesn't have a date constraint. Is that how you want it? So you'll have total patients for all time mixed with monthly data?

Comment: What I want to show is a forecast of patients that they will lose in the month to come. I want to show them the total number of patients then calculate the losses which is in the second select query.

Comment: If `PATIENT.mo`'s value represents the month, why the check against `PATIENT.rx_exp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    Count(patient_id) AS total,
    Count(case when rx_exp >= '2010-10-01' 
               AND rx_exp < '2010-11-01' then 1 end) AS losses,
    'October' AS `month`
FROM patient;
```

You could use this for the month but there's probably no point.

```
MAX(case when rx_exp >= '2010-10-01' 
     AND rx_exp < '2010-11-01' then patient2.mo end) AS `month`
```

Comment: Your query is giving me the correct totals. Thank you Martin!

Comment: Martin, what does the '1' do in the case stmt?

Comment: `COUNT` returns the number of `NON NULL` values passed to it. The `CASE` statement will evaluate to `1` if a row is in your target month or `NULL` otherwise. The `1` itself isn't important. You could use `0`, `X`, `patient_id` or any `NON NULL` value and get the same effect.

Comment: Martin, thanks for the explanation and the help. Regarding the month, I'm using other functions to determine the next month and omitted them in my example for brevity.